# Toggable menu in JQuery. Not sure how to save state

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu set up this way:

```
<div id='top-navigation'>
    <ul>
    <li><a class='top-nav-button-unclicked' href='#'>SUBJECT</a></li>
    <li><a class='top-nav-button-unclicked' href='#'>TOPIC</a></li>
    <li><a class='top-nav-button-unclicked' href='#'>PRESENTER</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='menu'>
    </div>
```

Basically, when I click on one of the links, I want the menu to pop up. I'm pretty new to jQuery, and I have this so far:

```
$('#menu').hide();

$(".top-nav-button-unclicked, .top-nav-button-clicked").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('top-nav-button-clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("top-nav-button-unclicked");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("top-nav-button-clicked");
    }
    $('#menu').toggle();
});
```

The problem with this, is that when I click on the first menu item "SUBJECT", the menu appears, and when I click "TOPIC", I want menu to stay open (technically, the menu results will change when I add ajax to it)

Basically, I'm not sure how to keep state as to which button is calling Menu. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a closure (or global property - ick!) and store something identifying the last link clicked (e.g. `$(this).text()`, or even `this` which would be the link element itself) and then change behavior based on examining the current link clicked and the last link clicked.

Comment: that's cool, but perhaps there is an alternative to using .toggle() ?

Comment: **check this fiddle..** http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/36MFw/ Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `.toggle()`, but you don't really want it to toggle each time.  If that's the case, then you should just compute whether you want it visible or not and set that specific state rather than use `.toggle()`.  You can also pass a boolean to `.toggle()` to determine whether it shows or hides.